# Unlimited cash CSGO practice?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm practicing CSGO and I need unlimited money so I can buy whatever I want every round. What is the command for this if there is one?

Comment: Quick question; what and how are you practicing CSGO?

Comment: Also just consider playing on Deathmatch if you are practicing weapon aiming etc. unless you need the game modes (hostage rescue, bomb defuse etc.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `mp_afterroundmoney 16000`, which will give you, and everyone else, up to 16 000 money, which is the maximum, at the start of each round.

Answer (score 10):

It appears the maximum money a player can have is 65535, the command I'm currently using to make this happen is:

```
sv_cheats 1;
mp_buy_anywhere 1;
mp_maxmoney 65535;
mp_startmoney 65535;
mp_afterroundmoney 65535;
mp_restartgame 1;
```

Comment: `MAX_UNSIGNED_SHORT`?

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 not sure what you mean?

Comment: The variable is probabaly implemented as a short whose maximum value is 65535

Comment: Ahh, yes I thought the same when I noticed the limit.

Answer (score 4):

Type these:

```
sv_cheats 1;
mp_buy_anywhere 1;
mp_maxmoney 65535;
mp_startmoney 65535;
mp_afterroundmoney 65535;
mp_restartgame 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

> mp_maxmoney 60000

Enables your maximum money to be 60.000

> mp_startmoney 60000

To get more than 16k..

Answer (score 2):

Open up console and write:

> sv_cheats 1
>
> impulse 101

Note: This will only give you 16000 money, so you will have to redo the command if you spend all.

Comment: Which unfortunately, forces him to re input command every round. 3ventic's solution works far better.